# SplFileObject __toString inheritance

Tags: php, inheritance, tostring, splfileobject

I've got a class that extends SplFileObject and implements a `__toString` method, but I seem to get inconsistent behaviour, depending on how the method is called. Sometimes the parent method is called, and sometimes the child method. Can anyone explain why this happens?

```
class Something extends \SplFileObject {
    public function __toString() {
        return 'calling __toString';
    }
}

$something = new Something('test.php');
echo $something; // 'calling __toString'
echo (string) $something; // 'test.php'
echo $something->__toString(); // 'calling __toString'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like old behavior.

Testing in php 5.4+ yields expected behavior, while 5.3 yielded what you saw

http://codepad.viper-7.com/aZgP1h

seemingly related bugs:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=26962
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60452

Comment: Ahh. So it may have been a bug that's been fixed? I'm currently on PHP 5.3.8.

Comment: It's interesting this was marked as "not a bug" when it was submitted as a bug for 5.3.8, but behavior changed in 5.4 lol https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60452 It looks like the dev misunderstood(misread) though.